# adding constraints to labels programmatically

Tags: objective-c, constraints

I have two labels,

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
[label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label1 setText:@"label1"];
[[self view] addSubview:label1];


// Create Label
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
[label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label2 setText:@"label2"];
[[self view] addSubview:label2];
```

I want to create a space between these two labels programmatically, but I am unsure of how to do so. I've tried using some of the answers from stackoverflow but they've given me errors.

Such as this one:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *c1 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:UIl.label2
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                          multiplier:1.0f
                          constant:8.0f];
```

Comment: What errors does it give ?Also I suggest using the masonry for autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the masonry for applying constraints programmatically.By using masonry , you could do simply:

**Step1-** Constraint the label 1

```
[label1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.view.mas_top); 
        make.left.equalTo(self.view.mas_left);
   }];
```

**Step2**-Constraint the label 2

```
 [label2 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.top.equalTo(label1.mas_top); 
            make.left.equalTo(label1.mas_left).with.offset(yourValue);
       }];
```